# Access/Edit data on android device from pc via internet (different networks)

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, udp

In the app i'm making, i want the user to be able to access the android phone(not the emulator) from pc via internet (different network connections) (not via usb).
I've been experimenting about this subject since i'm just a beginner in android and in networking.
This question [android socket communication through internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545066/android-socket-communication-through-internet) is related to what i'm asking, but there, the communication is made between windows and emulator.

Is it possible to make this communication and to be able to edit my contacts for example?
If yes, can someone please provide some code snippet?

Thank you.